# I am having a Problem Uploading an image in pygame

Tags: pygame

So I am currently trying to make a video game with other members of my coding class and I am having trouble Uploading an image in pygame. This is the code here

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
X = 400
Y = 400
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y ))
pygame.display.set_caption('Image')
image = pygame.image.load("BootLeg.jpg") 
while True : 
  display_surface.fill(white)
  display_surface.blit(image, (0, 0))
  for event in pygame.event.get() :
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
      pygame.quit()
      quit()`enter code here`
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The `pygame.display.update()` is not in the loop,

Comment: You will find your code easier to read (and debug) if you use an indentation of 4 spaces.  @TheBigKahuna is correct, and you probably would have noticed this bug yourself with better indentation.

Comment: so I put the pygame.display.update() in the loop and it still didn't work.It is telling me that it couldn't open "BootLeg.jpg".

Comment: Do you have the image in another folder, if the image is not in the same directory (folder) then you put the full path

Answer (score 0):

If `BootLeg.png` is not in the same folder as your python file it won't work.

`image = pygame.image.load("folder/BootLeg.png")`

If that still doesn't work, try doing this:

`image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("folder", "BootLeg.png"))`